# How to identify a boosted post via Facebook's Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads

Does anyone know what field is used to identify a post that has been boosted on Facebook?  I was hoping 'promotion_status' on the posts edge would help but that doesn't seem to be it.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using the `boosted_object_id` edge from the `campaigns` field on an `ad` account.  This is is the second half of the standard `page_post` format of posts.